# JSON.parse error is giving error with double quotes string

Tags: javascript, json

Why is it that

```
//Code
JSON.parse("{'name':'Khushal Khan'}");
```

results in this error

```
//Resposnse
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '
```

while this works perfectly

```
//Code
JSON.parse('{"name":"Khushal Khan"}');
```

Output:

```
//Response
Object {name: "Khushal Khan"}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the type of quote used in your JSON string, not the outer quotes. The JSON specification only allows for double quoted strings. You could use either type of quote to actually pass your JSON string to the `parse()` function, though.

From the [JSON spec](http://json.org):

[image: JSON string]

Comment: I.e., the single-quotes `'` need to be double-quotes `"`.

Comment: and here i am using double quotes but it still gives error `JSON.parse("{\"name\", \"Khushal Khan\"}");`

Comment: That's because of the comma, it should be a colon: `JSON.parse("{\"name\": \"Khushal Khan\"}");`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not that your JavaScript string uses `"` characters but that your JSON strings do not.

JSON is not JavaScript. JSON strings must be delimited by `"` characters.

From [the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627):

```
string = quotation-mark *char quotation-mark
```

and

```
quotation-mark = %x22      ; "
```

Comment: If you really want to wrap your JSON strings in double quotes, then you can escape the internal quotes like so: `"{\"name\":\"Khushal Khan\"}"`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not with double quoted string, but the json should have no single quotes as delimiters.