# Convert string to array in javsacript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object

i have a string containg an array. i can convert it using loop over string with different conditions but that will be slow. so is there any direct way to convert string which has array in it to an actuall array?
my javascript string looks like this

```
arr_str = '["value1", "value2", "value3"]'
```

i want to convert it in array something like this

```
arr = ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
```

Comment: `JSON.parse(arr_str)`

Comment: use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: in my case its not working. the error is Unexpected token ''', "['500', 'Large']" is not valid JSON

Comment: i have to do something like this:
 let arr_str = obj.innerHTML;
let arr = JSON.parse(arr_str);

Comment: You can do it like this: `JSON.parse("['500', 'Large']".replaceAll("'", '"'))`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101353/json-parse-error-is-giving-error-with-double-quotes-string

JSON has a strict quotation marks spec, so you need to switch them in your string.